# nesting multiple levels of array.map()

Tags: javascript

I have javascript array with three objects that each have an array (teamLineup) with two more objects (team) that each have another array (starters) which finally has the objects (player.name) I am trying to extract. The three top-level objects have the following structure:

```
let game1 = { teamLineup: [{
      team: {
        actual: {
          starters: [{
            player: {name: 'Joe'},
            player: {name: 'Kim'}
          }]
        }
      }
    },{
      team: {
        actual: {
          starters: [{
            player: {name: 'John'},
            player: {name: 'Shauna'}
          }]
        }
      }
    }]
  }

(game2....game3)
```

I am attempting to reduce the original array into a single array with only the player names as strings.

```
let games = [game1, game2, game3]

let allStartingPlayers = games.map(a => a.teamLineup.map( b => b.team.actual.starters.map(c => c.player.name)))

console.log(allStartingPlayers);
```

Sample output:

```
[ [ [ 'Kim' ], [ 'Shauna' ] ],
  [ [ 'Nicole' ], [ 'Jennifer' ] ],
  [ [ 'Sandy' ], [ 'David' ] ] ]
```

There are two issues. First, it only grabs the second player.name in each starters array. Second, it returns 3 nested arrays.

Comment: `[{ player: {name: 'Joe'}, player: {name: 'Kim'} }]` is invalid.

Comment: Son of a.... thank you, it now loops through correctly! I simplified the example above and have been testing it out before posting here and that typo was stopping me from realizing I have the right code! Thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need 2 `map`. One for the main array and one for the `starters` array.

Then you can use `[].concat(...arr)` to flatten the results.

```js
let game1 = { teamLineup: [{
    team: {
      actual: {
        starters: [
          {player: {name: 'Joe'}},
          {player: {name: 'Kim'}}
        ]
      }
    }
  },{
    team: {
      actual: {
        starters: [
          {player: {name: 'John'}},
          {player: {name: 'Shauna'}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
};

let game2 = { teamLineup: [{
    team: {
      actual: {
        starters: [
          {player: {name: 'Albert'}},
          {player: {name: 'Samantha'}}
        ]
      }
    }
  },{
    team: {
      actual: {
        starters: [
          {player: {name: 'Jina'}},
          {player: {name: 'Rob'}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
};

const games = [game1, game2];

const result = [].concat(...[].concat(...games.map(game => game.teamLineup.map(g => g.team.actual.starters.map(s => s.player.name)))));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: There are 3 games in an array though, When I remove the first map it doesn't loop though all the games.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is wrong. I.e. the starters array. You need to have each player as one object separately.

About the second problem of having multiple nested arrays, you can use forEach() to iterate over the objects and at the end only push the player.name into the results.

See below.

```js
let game1 = { teamLineup: [{
      team: {
        actual: {
          starters: [
            {player: {name: 'Joe'}},
            {player: {name: 'Kim'}}
          ]
        }
      }
    },{
      team: {
        actual: {
          starters: [
            {player: {name: 'John'}},
            {player: {name: 'Shauna'}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }]
  };

let game2 = { teamLineup: [{
      team: {
        actual: {
          starters: [
            {player: {name: 'Joe2'}},
            {player: {name: 'Kim2'}}
          ]
        }
      }
    },{
      team: {
        actual: {
          starters: [
            {player: {name: 'John2'}},
            {player: {name: 'Shauna2'}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }]
  };

let game3 = { teamLineup: [{
      team: {
        actual: {
          starters: [
            {player: {name: 'Joe3'}},
            {player: {name: 'Kim3'}}
          ]
        }
      }
    },{
      team: {
        actual: {
          starters: [
            {player: {name: 'John3'}},
            {player: {name: 'Shauna3'}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }]
  };
  
let games = [game1, game2, game3]

let allStartingPlayers = [];

games.forEach(a => a.teamLineup.forEach( b => b.team.actual.starters.forEach(c => allStartingPlayers.push(c.player.name))))

console.log(allStartingPlayers);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all looks like you lost some curly bracket. At your sample you write

```
starters: [{
        player: {name: 'Joe'},
        player: {name: 'Kim'}
      }]
```

which mean just

```
starters[{player:{name: 'Kim'}}]
```

So, maybe, we can rewrite this part of code as

```
starters: [
       {player: {name: 'Joe'}},
       {player: {name: 'Kim'}}
        ]
```

Then, from my humble opinion, you can mix reduce and map like this

```
let allStartingPlayers = games.reduce((a,v) => a.concat(v.teamLineup.reduce( (a,b) =>a.concat(b.team.actual.starters.map(c => c.player.name)),[])),[]);
```